# Copy values of multiple cells to another spreadsheet based on criteria of another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet that is using RSLINX to gather data from a machine. I can see the values changing. However, I need to copy those values to another spreadsheet every time the test is complete. There are multiple tests so the next test needs to populate below the last test in the spreadsheet. I know a macro will be needed but have no idea

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try to provide a simple sample here.